# Getting list item values without using Foreach statement

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to convert the code below to a LINQ expression, including the printout part.
Is that possible without using any loop statement?

```
public void PrintMinMaxAvg(List<Packet> packets)
{
  foreach (var packet in packets)
  {
    var min = packet.Values.Min();
    var max = packet.Values.Max();
    var avg = packet.Values.Average();
    Console.WriteLine($"min: {min}, max: {max}, avg: {avg}");    
  }
}
```

I was trying with something like:

```
packets.Select(x => Console.WriteLine($"min: {x.Values.Min()}, max: {x.Values.Max()}, avg: {x.Values.Average()}"));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why you don't want to use loop? when you use select internally it will iterate over the list.

Comment: What is the loop even for? It looks like you are printing the same string many times....?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it imposes parameters on the solution that seem arbitrary and the question therefore is unlikely to benefit future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really, really, want to avoid `foreach`, you could project to a full string separated by line breaks and print that:

```
var result = "\n".Join(packets.Select(p => string.Format(
                                     "min: {0}, max: {1}, avg: {2}",
                                     p.Values.Min(),
                                     p.Values.Max(),
                                     p.Values.Average()
                                     )
                       );

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

or alter your `Select` slightly (so that it returns a value with each iteration):

```
packets.Select(x => { Console.WriteLine($"min: {x.Values.Min()}, max: {x.Values.Max()}, avg: {x.Values.Average()}"; return null; }));
```

But note that `Join` (and Linq) use loops internally, so you're not really avoiding any loops, just *hiding* them.

> It is part of an interview question.

Okay that makes more sense. Interview questions like this are geared to see how you tackle a problem, not necessarily to get the "right" answer. Given those constraints, you could do something like the joining above, or do a `Select` query with side-effects, but it may be good to know why these are different that an explicit `foreach`. Or, they may have strong opinions about anti-patters like side effects and want to see how quick you are to use them. Or say something like "You *could* do it this way, but here's why you *shouldn't*".

Unfortunately questions like these are also used to see if you know some "trick" that the interviewer knows (and probably learned from a similar question), either to make them think they're smarter or to see how you react to unreasonable requests. I call these "guess what I'm thinking" questions which I'm not a fan of.

Comment: That's a good solution too, but neither .Join() was allowed.

Comment: Sounds like very arbitrary criteria to answer this question. The solution isn't "good" in the sense that it can allocate a lot of memory for a large list. It's a solid attempt to answer within the parameters of the question.

Answer (score 0):

its pretty much the same as a loop but you could just do .ForEach(). Select is more like .map() in js.

`packets.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"min: {x.Values.Min()}, max: {x.Values.Max()}, avg: {x.Values.Average()}"));`

Comment: Thanks, but it should not use any kind of foreach statement. Neither the one you propose.

Comment: The extension method .ForEach() is available on `List<T>` but not more generally on `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @Richard why not? What's the problem with using `foreach`?

Comment: It is part of an interview question. I had the same idea of using packets.ForEach. Or even using select to retrieve a list of anonymous items (or strings) and then print it out using a foreach. But was not what the interviewers expected. And I don't really know what were they expecting.

Comment: @Richard In my view, it's a poor interview question because you're being asked how to do something contrary to the intended Linq pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Linq borrows a concept from functional programming that a function should minimize [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). This allows predictable chaining of arbitrary extension methods.

The `List<T>.ForEach()` extension method breaks this concept.

I suggest modeling loops on the output of a Linq expression along the lines of:

```
var myLinq = source.SomeMethod().AnotherMethod.Select(...);
foreach (var element in myLinq)
    DoSomethingPossiblyHavingSideEffects
```